# Can't open jpg (Send from Python3 to C# over socket)?

Tags: c#, python, sockets

Hey all I'm fairly new to programming, done a bit of c# but totally new to Python.
I have send an image from my raspberry pi (python3) to my laptop (c#). I can se the bytes are send but I cant open the image, when it is received (re-created)? :(

btw this is my first post on stackoverflow, i hope you can help me :)

C# code (receiving):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;

namespace tmpRaspTcpServer
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            IPAddress localAdd = IPAddress.Parse("xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx");
            TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 8888);
            Console.WriteLine("Listen...");
            listener.Start();

            while (true)
            {

                TcpClient client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();

                NetworkStream nwStream = client.GetStream();
                byte[] buffer = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];

                int bytesRead = nwStream.Read(buffer, 0, client.ReceiveBufferSize);

                string dataReceived = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                Console.WriteLine("Reading bytes: " );

                FileStream fs = new FileStream("c:\\tmp\\file.jpg", FileMode.Create);

                TraditionalReceiveBinary(nwStream, fs);
            }
        } 

        private static void TraditionalReceiveBinary(NetworkStream nwstream, FileStream fs)
        {
            // read the file in chunks of 1KB
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

            int bytesRead;
            while ((bytesRead = nwstream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
            {

                fs.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);

                Console.Write("."); // a dot for each kb
            }
            fs.Flush();

        }
    }
}
```

Python3 code (sending):

```
import socket
HOST, PORT = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx", 8888

image = open('image.jpg', 'rb')
image_data = image.read()
image.close()

socketData = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
socketData.connect((HOST,PORT))

socketData.sendall(image_data)
```

I dont get any error, and the c# app makes dots in the console when i send the image, but the file is "corrupted" or something :(

I have tried with different encoding and headers - but no luck.

Comment: Usual reason is either not reading the file as binary (but I can see you do that) or not writing it as binary - can't see where you specify binary writing.

Comment: After i read it binary "  'rb'   " should i also write it binary to the stream? 
- If so can you make a quick coment on how that line of code might look like? 
 Thanks so far :)

Comment: Not needed (not sure if it's even possible) - it's the file read/write where you need to ensure binary.

Comment: What value does 'FileMode.Create' have, or what does it mean? Is that specifying binary? Also, compare the file length at the source and target, are they the same? How about creating md5 signature for both - if the same then the transfer isn't corrupting the file - or if they are different then it is. You could print the length of the data read from file at the sender, and the length of data written to file at the receiver, are they the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're discarding the first TcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize bytes that you are reading from the socket at:

```
int bytesRead = nwStream.Read(buffer, 0, client.ReceiveBufferSize);
```

This is going to corrupt your output file.